# `boost::asio` - Making a specific function not to run in parallel

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I have an asynchronous function with a callback wrapped to be used as a coroutine, exactly like in the example from `asio`:
https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio/blob/fa27820c05afd740fa2adc1ecfb9da5afe026443/asio/src/examples/cpp20/operations/c_callback_wrapper.cpp

In this example, the C-based API function `read_input` is wrapped by `async_read_input` and can be used, for example, like this:

```
co_await async_read_input("Enter your name", asio::use_awaitable);
```

The problem is, my `read_input` is not thread safe (I call `io_context::run` from multiple threads). It is my understanding that `asio::strand` is supposed to be useful, in this case, but I don't know how. If I do something like

```
co_await async_read_input("Enter your name", asio::bind_executor(strand, asio::use_awaitable));
```

it is my understanding that it does kind of the opposite of what I want, making the completions happen in a certain order while still letting `read_input` to be run in parallel. And if I use `post`/`dispatch`/`defer` (which I don't even know how / if possible) I cannot `co_await` it. I still want to `co_await` it.

Answer (score 0):

Strands don't prevent operations from running concurrently. In fact, that's counter to the entire design of Asio: it specicically exists to facilitate interfacing with (inherently) asynchronous peripherals or services. In effect, many async operations *can only* run concurrently, e.g. when they happen in hardware.

You **can** use a strand to avoid **initiating** operations concurrently, though that doesn't immediately mean you won't start multiple concurrent operations unless you also make sure that the prior operation has completed beforehand. This would normally imply some kind of queuing.

What I think it boils down for the application you describe, I think is this:

- Your classical API is not thread-aware
- Your interface must be thread-aware
- The simplest solution then would be to have *classical* thread synchronization inside the "black box" of your API wrapper (*"`read_input`"*) so the rest of the world can simply treat it as a true async service, just with some higher latency depending on the number of invocations already pending.

Very simplistically that might translate to something like:

```
void read_input(char const* prompt, void (*cb)(void*, char const*), void* arg) {
    std::thread([prompt = std::string(prompt), cb, arg] {
        static std::mutex mx;
        std::string       line;
        {
            std::lock_guard lk(mx);
            std::cout << prompt << ": ";
            std::cout.flush();
            std::getline(std::cin, line);
        }
        cb(arg, line.c_str());
    }).detach();
}
```

### Side Note

> **Q.** And if I use post/dispatch/defer (which I even know how / if possible) I cannot co_await it

I don't recommend it for various reasons, but it **could** be quite fine iff you replaced the `std::thread` with an equivalent `post` to a strand. The problem comes when your wrapped API likely does blocking work which can inhibit progress on your service threads.

Again very simplistically:

```
void read_input(char const* prompt, void (*cb)(void*, char const*), void* arg) {
    static auto some_strand = make_strand(asio::system_executor{});
    asio::post(some_strand, [prompt = std::string(prompt), cb, arg] {
        std::string       line;
        std::cout << prompt << ": ";
        std::cout.flush();
        std::getline(std::cin, line);
        cb(arg, line.c_str());
    });
}
```

Comment: You say I can use a strand to avoid initiating operations concurrently. In the example in the question, the initiation is the code in `read_input` that starts the thread, right? If so, this is exactly what I want. How do I do that?

Comment: The initiating function is `async_read_input`. Even though it may be serialized, the threads will (obviously) still run concurrently.

Comment: How do I serialize the initiating function?

Comment: You tell me, you never showed its internals, and that's (the only thing) what it depends on. If it is truly _"exactly like in the example"_ then by definition it is blocking, which means you *need* to pool it on some other thread. My second ultrasimplistic already gives you the gist, but you may want to use a different strand instance. An alternative may be to [post to (a strand associated with) a 1-element thread pool](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2368649ec8602c9b). All it comes down to is classic synchronization/queueing, whether you use Asio building blocks to achieve or not.